# Webpack not excluding hashed javascript files in html files with HTMLWebPackPlugin

Tags: javascript, caching, webpack

I inherited a Webpack configuration and it's in bad shape. I am trying to implement a sane caching strategy which requires adding hashes to the end of the outputted javascript files.

Right now when the browser views HTML files the injected `<script>` tags are missing hashes or timestamps (ex: `<script src="main.js">`. So whenever the javascript gets updated, the browser assumes it has the most up to date versions of the javascript files. In order to solve this problem I can set the hash property to true in the HTMLWebpackPlugin block (however this creates another problem). The config also uses the HtmlWebpackExcludeAssetsPlugin to exclude certain assets from being injected into the HTML. Don't ask me why but I'm working with what I've got. Here is an example:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: "index.html",
  template: path.join(process.cwd(), "src", "templates", "home.ejs"),
  inject: true,
  hash: false,
  excludeAssets: [
    /(availabilityView|availability|press|legal|accessibility|visit|addons).(js|css)$/
  ],
  minify: {
    removeComments: true,
    collapseWhitespace: false
  }
}),
```

Setting `hash: false` results in the following:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/manifest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Setting `hash: true` within the block works as expected and adds hash values inside of the HTML file. Like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/manifest.js?bf93a9f5cbf821b8c89b"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/vendor.js?bf93a9f5cbf821b8c89b"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js?bf93a9f5cbf821b8c89b"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/availability.js?bf93a9f5cbf821b8c89b"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/visit.js?bf93a9f5cbf821b8c89b"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/press.js?bf93a9f5cbf821b8c89b"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/legal.js?bf93a9f5cbf821b8c89b"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/accessibility.js?bf93a9f5cbf821b8c89b"></script>
```

The problem: now the javascript files in the excludeAssets array are being injected into the HTML above the last body tag.

The question: How can I inject hashes to the end of the javascript files in the html while simultaneously excluding the javascript files in excludeAssets?

Here is a gist of the entire config (remember that I inherited it): https://gist.github.com/joelhoelting/125132e1ce0a90e370564e7214a9e0f6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the regex that gets passed into `excludeAssets` was failing to select the hashed filenames. The following regex worked as intended:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: "index.html",
  template: path.join(process.cwd(), "src", "templates", "home.ejs"),
  inject: true,
  hash: false,
  excludeAssets: [
    /(availabilityView.*|availability.*|press.*|legal.*|accessibility.*|visit.*)/
  ],
  minify: {
    removeComments: true,
    collapseWhitespace: false
  }
}),
```